# How to convert () => number to number in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have issue with converting.
I getting error like this:

> Type '() => number' is not assignable to type 'number'.

In this part of code:

```
...
for (let g of parcelData.geom){
      const point = [];
      let lat : number;
      lat = g.lat; // error there
...
```

Somebody can tell me how i can convert this to classic number?

Comment: What is the type of g.lat ?

Comment: @Arash (method) ReportAllUSAGeometry.lat(): number

Comment: try lat = g.lat()

Comment: Thanks, sometimes i can't find simple way and choosing a way far far away from home :D

Comment: @ober your welcome :) I also added the answer of this post ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`g.lat()` is a function and you should assign it like below.

`lat = g.lat()`

Answer (score 0):

> Note

first of all check data type of `parcelData.geom`

```
console.log(typeof parcelData.geom);
```

then change below according to that

```
let lat : number;<----then change this
  lat = g.lat;
```